# What is the Op Category?

Tags: category-theory

By what is, I do not mean the construction, the construction is easy. What I mean is what does the Op category really represent to us in terms of the original? Oh sure, it represents the dual... but that is circular reasoning.

For every category $\textbf{C}$ there is a mirror image category $\textbf{C}^{op}$. When we "walk" through $\textbf{C}$ we are walking through $\textbf{C}^{op}$ "contravariantly" BUT $f^{op}$ does something different for us.

So the question really is, what is $f^{op}$ actually doing to the internal structure? If I have some category $\textbf{C}$ and follow some path of arrows from a to b then in $\textbf{C}^{op}$ I have to take the path of arrows from b to a and this somehow tells me something relevant. In some sense it seems like an inverse. It is almost as if $f^{op}$ is some "generalized" inverse that takes us back from where we came. If that sorta is true then $\textbf{C}^{op}$ is sort of an "inverse" category that tracks all changes, a sort of "undo" class that allows us, in theory, to go back.

If that is true then it would not be much different than just saying that for every arrow in a category there is an op-arrow that sort of acts like a generalized inverse that in theory lets us reverse any path of arrows.

I guess this would make total since if a category that has inverse for all arrows is self-dual(hence the generalized inverses are just normal inverses and).

Anyways, I'm trying to get some type of intuitive understanding of the opposite category so that when it is talked about I can actually reason from it in a concrete way. This inverse analogy seems like it would work but it also seems that $f^{op}$ doesn't necessarily, by definition, have to have any relation to $f$, it just has to be *any* arrow that reverses direction.

This leads me to another problem I have, in the definition of the opposite category it seems that we can actually have many opposite categories. Only the arrow has to be reverses, but the definition doesn't say anything about it having to have any other relationship to $f$ other than exchanging the domain and codomain. Of course, it is clear that this is not true, I haven't been able to figure out way from the book.

I guess this is really ultimately asking how does $f^{op}$ really relate to $f$ rather than just saying it is the opposite?

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that we generally assign some semantic understanding to categories (e.g. the "category *of sets*", the "category of *groups*", and so on), formally speaking, a category is simply a collection of objects and morphisms that satisfy some laws. If you took a well-known category and presented it simply in terms of an abstract set of objects, morphisms, and the way the morphisms composed, you may have a very hard time working out what the category represented. Not every category has a meaningful semantic interpretation.

When you take the dual of the category, you're performing a formal construction: though you might be starting with a category that has some semantic interpretation, its dual, a priori, does not. That is, there is no reason to expect that the opposite morphisms may be interpreted as a meaningful concept with respect to the original morphisms.

In some cases, they can. A category being self-dual is an obvious example, as you point out. There are non-trivial examples, though, which often arise in [Stone duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_duality)-type situations, where you have a contravariant correspondence between topological and algebraic structure. For instance, the category of sets is equivalent to the opposite of the category of [complete atomic Boolean algebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Set#OppositeCategory). However, this is by no means the norm and, in general, the dual really is most easily described as "turning the arrows around".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116102/discussion-on-answer-by-varkor-what-is-the-op-category).

Comment: Nice answer (+1).

Answer (score 1):

> This leads me to another problem I have, in the definition of the opposite category it seems that we can actually have many opposite categories. Only the arrow has to be reverses, but the definition doesn't say anything about it having to have any other relationship to f other than exchanging the domain and codomain. Of course, it is clear that this is not true, I haven't been able to figure out way from the book.

I will try to clear up your confusion here.

Suppose we have a category $\mathcal C$. This is how we form the opposite category $\mathcal C^\text{op}$.

- For every object $A$ in $\mathcal C$ we have an object $A^\text{op}$ in $\mathcal C^\text{op}$. There are no other objects.
- For every morphism $f : A \to B$ in $\mathcal C$, we have a morphism $f^\text{op} : B^\text{op} \to A^\text{op}$. There are no other morphisms.
- We also have to specify how composition works (we will denote composition in $\mathcal C$ by $\circ$, and in $\mathcal C^\text{op}$ by $\circ ^\text{op}$).

If we have two morphisms $A^\text{op} \to B^\text{op}$ and $B^\text{op} \to C^\text{op}$ we know they are of the form $f^\text{op}$ and $g^\text{op}$ for some $f : B \to A$ and $g : C \to B$ in $\mathcal C$. Then we will compose them according to this rule:

$g^\text{op} \circ^\text{op} f^\text{op} = (f \circ g)^\text{op}$

This is the full definition of the opposite category. It is not too hard to verify that it is indeed a category: we need to check that $\circ ^\text{op}$ is associative, and that there are identities ($id_A ^\text{op}$ is the identity on $A^\text{op}$). It is common to not write the $``{^\text{op}}''$, but for the sake of clarity---so that we do not get confused about which category we are in---I will leave it.

So, what is the relation between $f$ and $f^\text{op}$? In some sense, they are the same morphism. This is because $f^\text{op}$ composes in the same way as $f$ does, except *in the other direction*.

In particular, $f^\text{op}$ is not merely "any arrow [in $\mathcal C$, I assume you meant] that reverses the direction", because it's not an arrow of $\mathcal C$. It's also not in any sense an inverse to $f$, because they are in different categories, and cannot be composed.

So, the arrows of $\mathcal C ^\text{op}$ are precisely the arrows of $\mathcal C$, but we pretend they go in reverse. We denote this by writing $f^\text{op} : B ^\text{op} \to A ^\text{op}$ for the reverse of the arrow $f : A \to B$. To calculate a composition of these "reversed arrows", we unreverse them, compose them in the way that $\mathcal C$ tells us to, and reverse the result.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116101/discussion-on-answer-by-daniel-mroz-what-is-the-op-category).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I regard the opposite category. If $\mathscr{A}$ is a category, then $\mathscr{A}^{op}$ is obtained by reversing arrows (as you probably know already). What does an arrow $f^{op}$ in $\mathscr{A}^{op}$ mean? Actually,... it means almost nothing. For example, take the category $\textbf{Set}$. A morphism in $\textbf{Set}^{op}$ means what? It is definitely not an ordinary function, because there is a morphism $\S\to\emptyset$ for any set $S$, which makes no sense to call this a function. And let's be clear, the construction of an opposite category is not meant to give some concrete applications. In the end, we first invent it to capture the notion of duality. Given a statement in category theory, you can get the dual statement immediately by invoking the opposite category. But we often rewrite the dual statement to eliminate the opposite category. A basic example is a covariant/contravariant functor. A contravariant functor is a covariant functor from the opposite category. By defining this way, we don't even have to explicitly define what a contravariant functor really is. But it offers no contextual meaning. In the end, we still have to translate it back to the version without using the opposite category. The opposite category is meant to be a tool only, concrete interpretation is almost non-existing.

It also doesn't stop you to learn more category theory without really getting this concept fully. I suggest you continue without worrying too much about this. As you learn more, you probably will understand what opposite category "really is"